# Is there a way to keep non standard DOM element ( in this case '<% .. %>' ) in the output ? see my code below:

Tags: php, domdocument

Is there a way to keep non standard DOM element ( in this case '<% .. %>' ) in the output ?

see my code below:

```
$html = '<html>';
$html .= '<body>';
$html .= '<% recipient.name %> ';
$html .='</body>';
$html .='</html>';

$document = new \DOMDocument('1.0');
$internalErrors = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$document->loadHTML($html);

libxml_use_internal_errors($internalErrors);

$out = $document->saveHTML();
print $out;
```

I am getting this output:

```
<html>
<head><meta content="text/html; http-equiv=" content-type></head> 
<body> </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the input is valid XML, you could wrap the template tags in `<![CDATA[…]]>` and `loadXML` will treat them as text nodes:

```
$html = '<html>';
$html .= '<body>';
$html .= '<![CDATA[<% recipient.name %>]]>';
$html .='</body>';
$html .='</html>';

$document = new \DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($html);
print $document->saveHTML();

// <html><body><% recipient.name %></body></html>
```